# I receive childcare vouchers from my employer in UK but my Tier 2 general visa says "no public funds". What are the implications?

Tags: united-kingdom, resident-permit, uk-visa, uk-citizenship

I have a Tier 2 general visa with note that I have no access to public funds (NRPF). As part of my employee benefits I receive childcare vouchers from my employer which are deducted pre-tax.

My questions are:

1. Does this violate my visa requirements? If so, should I cancel my vouchers?
2. If this is not allowed, what should I do with vouchers that I have already received?
3. How will this impact my ILR and/or citizenship applications in future?

Thank you

Comment: I think you should clarify this with your employer, however AFAIK childcare vouchers are not included in the list of state-paid benefits, tax credits or housing assistance listed as within the ‘no recourse to public funds’ restrictions https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/public-funds--2/public-funds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless your employer is the government (or local government), I don't see how anything your employer gives you could be considered "public funds". But the fact that the vouchers are paid free of tax, I can see why this could be confusing. Having said that, if this is a tax credit to which everyone is entitled then it doesn't count as "receiving public funds". Check the link provided by @Traveller about public funds: https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/public-funds--2/public-funds

As suggested in a comment, you need to talk to your employer (their accounting department, or possibly HR), to clarify this.

If it is determined that the vouchers are not allowed, then I think you need to tell your employer to stop giving them to you, and return any you have already received. Get documentation to say that you did this, if this is the case (in case it comes up later).

As long as everything is above-board, it should not affect any future immigration-related processes you go through, such as ILR or citizenship. It sounds like the employer instigated this scheme, and not you. The fact that you questioned it can only go in your favour if it ever comes up.